# Получить содержимое ImageView

Tags: android

Как проверить содержимое `ImageView`?

Точнее, название содержимого:

Есть `ImageView` с каким-то изображением, и если там то изображение, какое мне надо - сделать что-то.

Comment: Вам надо получить имя файла, который отображвется в `ImageView`?

Comment: Да! подскажите как это сделать)

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется, что это не так просто, как должно быть. Дело в том, что `ImageView` не обзательно содержит изображение от файла, может и содержать данные от массива байтов. Поэтому, я думаю, что надо сравнивать битмапы.

Вот метод сравнивать содержимое `ImageView` c файлом:

```
private boolean matchesFile(ImageView imageView, String fileName) {
    imageView.buildDrawingCache();
    Bitmap bmap1 = imageView.getDrawingCache();
    Bitmap bmap2 = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fileName);
    return bmap1.sameAs(bmap2);
}
```